# lubridate ymd_hms() strange output when time shift is included

Tags: r, time, lubridate, datetime-conversion

I am confused with the output of the `ymd_hms()`of the `lubridate package`. 
I scraped some data frome the web containing a time stamp of the following format:

```
time_series <- c("2019-10-17 23:43:50+00:00", "2019-10-17 23:43:50+01:00")
```

If I use `ymd_hms()` on time series I get the following:

```
 library(ludridate)    
 ymd_hms(time_series)
 # [1] "2019-10-17 23:43:50 UTC" "2019-10-17 22:43:50 UTC"
```

Why is the second time stamp converted one hour earlier? From my understanding and also on the website where I scraped the data it should be one hour later (+01:00):

```
#[1] "2019-10-17 23:43:50 UTC" "2019-10-18 00:43:50 UTC"
```

What do I get wrong? And how do I change the behavior of ymd_hms() to get the desired output?

Comment: I believe that `2019-10-17 23:43:50+01:00` means that this is 23:43:50 in UTC+1 so that in UTC this should be 22:43:50 which seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is an old question. Piotr K is absolutely right. Time is always communicated in relation to coordinated universal time (UTC). So the time stamp `hh:mm:ss+01:00` means UTC + 1hour. As `ymd_hms()` converts all timestamps to UTC by default the above behavior is absolutely correct.